# JsonSerializer: discriminate the Kind of DateTime objects

Tags: c#, jsonserializer

I have a dynamic object that contains dates (among other data).

Some of these dates have Kind UTC and others have Kind Local, eg:

```
var dynamicObject = new 
{
     utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow,    //This one has Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc
     localDate = DateTime.Now      //This one has Kind = DateTimeKind.Local
}
```

And then I have a JsonSerializer that works as follows:

```
var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
                                            //                       ^
                                            //                  Notice this

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(isoDateTimeConverter);

var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting };

var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
serializer.Serialize(writer, dynamicObject);

writer.Flush();
```

Which creates a JSON string as this:

```
{
     "utcDate":"2019-05-02T19:52:20Z",
     "localDate":"2019-05-02T15:52:20Z"
}
```

This is expected because of how my `isoDateTimeConverter` is currently defined.

But I'd like to serialize as follows:

```
{
     "utcDate":"2019-05-02T19:52:20Z",
     "localDate":"2019-05-02T15:52:20"    // <--- no Z
}
```

Meaning that I'd like to add a 'Z' **only when the Kind of the DateTime is Utc**.

Is this possible with `IsoDateTimeConverter` and/or `JsonSerializerSettings` ?

Comment: Did you try without setting a `DateTimeFormat`?

Comment: Yes, indeed it adds correctly the Z depending on the Kind. BUT... it also adds miliseconds that make it non ISO 8601 format, example: `2019-05-02T16:12:26.7134289-04:00`, or: `2019-05-02T20:12:26.7134289Z`

Comment: Milliseconds are valid for ISO 8601... [You could also use `K` instead of `'Z'`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier)

Comment: is the `-04:00` part valid in ISO 8601 ?

Comment: Yep: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

Comment: Is `7134289` valid for miliseconds? I thought the format was: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` (only 3 digits for miliseconds).

Comment: Fractional seconds are indeed allowed by ISO 8601 - to any length.

Comment: Hmm well then.. I'm not sure why I ever added that `SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(isoDateTimeConverter)` in my code. I will check my clientside code if something stops working

Comment: Sorry, I was writing a more complete answer outside of the comment train. ISO 8601 allows for arbitrary precision, but both your client and your server need to agree, or ignore any extra precision. You can also use `K` as mentioned if you're concerned about portability.

Comment: Just to clarify my last comment ("I'm not sure why I ever added that SerializerSettings.Converters"). I just found out: in my database I have `DATETIME` columns, not `DATETIMEOFFSET`. So every time I fetch with Linq, I get "Kind = Unspecified". This is why I was manually adding the "Z". (Until today, I was only saving UTC dates but I posted this question because I'm planning to save Local Dates too...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would either use `IsoDateTimeConverter` without setting the `DateTimeFormat`, which outputs the full `DateTime` value, with fractions of seconds, and a "Z" if the `DateTimeKind` is `UTC` or a time zone offset in "+-HH:mm" format if `Local` (and the empty string if `None`).

Otherwise, the [`K` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier) will format the value as you desire, appending the same values for the offset from UTC.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dynamicObject = new
        {
            utcDate = DateTime.UtcNow, //This one has Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc
            localDate = DateTime.Now //This one has Kind = DateTimeKind.Local
        }

        ;
        var isoDateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter();
        isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssK";
        var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        serializerSettings.Converters.Add(isoDateTimeConverter);
        var s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        using (var w = new System.IO.StringWriter(s))
        using (var writer = new JsonTextWriter(w)
                   {Formatting = Formatting.Indented})
        {
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, dynamicObject);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    }
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gTewsm).

The ISO 8601 format allows for many variations of dates and times, to arbitrary precision. From [Wikipedia's article on ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times):

> There is no limit on the number of decimal places for the decimal fraction. However, the number of decimal places needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- You should not serialize `DateTime` values with `DateTimeKind.Local` values without an offset.  Since it's local time, the local offset should be provided.  Otherwise the receiver may interpret the value in *their* local time - which may be different than the sender's.
- [The `K` specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier), when paired with `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind`, properly serializes in all supported ISO 8601 formats:

  - `DateTimeKind.Utc` gets serialized with a `Z` appended
  - `DateTimeKind.Local` gets serialized with the local offset appended, such as `-07:00`
  - `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` gets serialized without anything appended
- These are the defaults already given by the `IsoDateTimeConverter`, which is the default converter for `DateTime` values.  Thus, in most cases you don't need to specify any converter at all.
- Fractional seconds to any length are allowed by ISO 8601.  The `RoundTripKind` style gives 7 decimals because that is the precision supported by `DateTime`.  Client side code in JavaScript generally supports only milliseconds, so extra decimals would be truncated when parsed on the client.
- If you *must* truncate decimals, then:

  ```
  isoDateTimeConverter.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssK";
  ```
- If you feel like you must truncate offsets for local time, the better way would be to set `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` using `DateTime.SpecifyKind` before serialization.
- If you feel like you should change this *globally*, then you would create your own `JsonConverter`.  You could inherit from the `IsoDateTimeConverter` and override the `ReadJson` and `WriteJson` methods, or you could just start directly from `JsonConverter`.  Since I don't recommend this approach, I won't add one here.